# Почему для работы нативных методов не нужны C++ библиотеки?

Tags: java, c++, библиотеки, jvm

В JVM есть нативные методы - код, написанный на C++. Тогда почему для работы JVM не нужны библиотеки, требующиеся для работы C++?

Переформулирую вопрос: в JVM есть C++ код, на разве для работы C++ не нужны какие-то библиотеки?

Comment: Вопрос очень спорный, т.к. вероятнее всего сама JVM написана на с, и вполне может использовать стандартные библиотеки с. Но при использовании из под с++ JVM нужно пользовать библиотеку JVM, если нужно что б JVM поняла что вы сделали.

Comment: Какие именно библиотеки вы имеете ввиду и с чего вы взяли, что они не нужны?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev 1)стандартные библиотеки C++, наверное.  2)Разве нельзя запустить java программу без установки стандартных C++ библиотек?

Comment: А разве стандартные библиотеки C++ нужно устанавливать? Они как правило встроены в многие современные OS. Часть стандартной библиотеки иногда вообще является частью ядра (для линукс).

Comment: требующиеся для работы C++ - это я так понял требующиеся для работы Visual Studio? Так VS это монстр, у которого несколько ГБ всяких разных либ, которые возможно ему и не нужны, но без них он не запустится. Как минимум он использует dot net framework, и кучу разных COM. Microsoft использовали свои наработки для VS, а разработчики Java использовали стандартный с.

Comment: "в JVM есть C++ код" - привидите код в вопросе и покажите как компилируете и линкуете. "но разве для работы C++ не нужны какие-то библиотеки?" - нужны. Ваш вопрос не понятен.

Comment: @0xdb не мой C++ код. Нативные методы в JVM - это разве не методы с  C++ кодом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужны, и Java несет их с собой в папке `jre\bin`.

Answer (score 2):

`JVM` поставляется вместе с пакетами `JRE` или `JDK`. Они и включают в себя скомпилированные файлы `C`.

Чтобы в этом убедиться, вы можете найти папки `include` и `lib` в папке где находится `Java`.

Папка `include` включает заголовочные файлы. А `lib` скомпилированные файлы.

Comment: Так причем тут это. Я читал, что в JVM есть код, написанный на C++. Но для выполнения C++ разве не нужны C++ либы(Microsoft Visual C++)?

Comment: @Anton238 Microsoft Visual C++ - это не "либа", а компилятор.